# JMeter Response Assertion Diff

Tags: jmeter

I'd like to view exactly what differs in my "actual" versus "expected" assertions. Is there a way to do this in JMeter?

Trivial example (my needs are for many lines of data):

Expected response (assertion): `"apple banana orange"`

Actual response: `"apple pear orange"`

In the above I'm looking for some sort of diff that shows what specifically is different about the expected vs actual. (Something to the effect of: "pear" in actual response, expected "banana")

Right now when a Text Response -> Substring assertion fails, jmeter let's me know that it fails and gives me the entire expected/actual strings back. I'm essentially looking for a specific diff of *what exactly differs* in the block of text.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is so generic, it's hard to say exactly what will work.

1. In many occasions **Response Assertion** with multiple conditions and RegEx can provide you the required output. For instance your example can be expressed as 3 conditions:

   [image]

   (although this RegEx works, I'm sure it could be improved, but you get the idea)

   So this Assertion would give you a more precise output, for example for input `apple pear orange`, the failure would be:

   > message expected to match /^[^ ]+ banana .*/

   This approach is good when you have a bunch of independent verifications, for each of which you want to get a result. However, it will stop at first failure, plus if you have, say 200 verifications, coding them becomes unfeasible.
2. A more powerful way is to use **BeanShell Assertion**, where you can code any rules and any output, using your example:

   [image]

   So for example input `apple pear orange`, the failure would be:

   > Assertion failure message: 2: banana mismatches pear

Answer (score 0):

You can add regular expression as post processor. Add default value as NOT_FOUND variable fruits

And add response assertion on Jmeter Variable on fruits with your assertion.